# Exception thrown at 0x6FDFDBF0 (vcruntime140.dll) in Main.exe

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm working on an assignment for school in C++ which contains a skeleton we have to begin with which also involves the SFML library which I've correctly imported. The skeleton is made up of 2 .cpp files, a .h header file and all the files in /Assets. Listed below are the three files.

Main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{

    Game theGame;

    theGame.loop();

    return 0;

}
```

Game.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{

    std::ifstream fileHndl;

    fileHndl.open("Assets/mapdata.txt");

    fileHndl >> mapCols;
    fileHndl >> mapRows;

    playerX = mapCols / 2;
    playerY = mapRows / 2;

    mapData = new int *[mapRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < mapRows; i++) {
        mapData[i] = new int[mapCols];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mapRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapCols; j++) {
            fileHndl >> mapData[i][j];
        }
    }

    window.create(sf::VideoMode(1280, 1024), "COMP2501 Demo");
    window.setFramerateLimit(5);

    playerTexture.loadFromFile("Assets/actor.png");
    playerTexture.setSmooth(true);
    playerSprite.setTexture(this->playerTexture);

    floorTexture.loadFromFile("Assets/floor.png");
    floorTexture.setSmooth(true);
    crateTexture.loadFromFile("Assets/crate.png");
    crateTexture.setSmooth(true);

    mapSprites = new sf::Sprite *[mapRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < mapRows; i++) {
        mapSprites[i] = new sf::Sprite[mapCols];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mapRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapCols; j++)
        {
            mapSprites[i][j].setPosition(j * 64, i * 64);
            if (mapData[i][j] == 1)
            {
                mapSprites[i][j].setTexture(this->floorTexture);
            }
            else
            {
                mapSprites[i][j].setTexture(this->crateTexture);
            }
        }
    }

}

Game::~Game()
{ }

void Game::loop()
{

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        inputs();
        update();
        render();
    }

}

void Game::inputs()
{

    sf::Event event;

    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
        }
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
    {
        if (this->mapData[this->playerX - 1][this->playerY] == 1)
        {
            this->playerX--;
        }

    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
    {
        if (this->mapData[this->playerX + 1][this->playerY] == 1)
        {
            this->playerX++;
        }
    }

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
    {
        if (this->mapData[this->playerX][this->playerY - 1] == 1)
        {
            this->playerY--;
        }

    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
    {
        if (this->mapData[this->playerX][this->playerY + 1] == 1)
        {
            this->playerY++;
        }
    }

}

void Game::update()
{ }

void Game::render()
{

    playerSprite.setPosition(playerY * 64, playerX * 64);
    window.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < mapRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mapCols; j++) {
            window.draw(mapSprites[i][j]);
        }
    }
    window.draw(playerSprite);
    window.display();

}
```

Game.h

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

class Game
{

    public:

        Game();
        ~Game();

        void loop();
        void inputs();
        void update();
        void render();

        sf::RenderWindow window;

        int playerX, playerY;
        sf::Texture playerTexture;
        sf::Sprite playerSprite;

        int mapRows, mapCols;
        int **mapData;

        sf::Sprite **mapSprites;

        sf::Texture floorTexture;
        sf::Texture crateTexture;

};
```

The program compiles correctly however at run-time it gives me the following.

```
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Main\Debug\Main.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Main\Debug\sfml-graphics-2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Main\Debug\sfml-window-2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Main\Debug\sfml-system-2.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-multibyte-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvoglv32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dbghelp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x4c0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1be8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winsta.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x1924 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1b50 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dinput.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\hid.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Main.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
Exception thrown at 0x6FDFDBF0 (vcruntime140.dll) in Main.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00477000.

The program '[6440] Main.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
vcruntime140.dll!memcpy(unsigned char * dst, unsigned char * src, unsigned long count) Line 634 Unknown
vcruntime140.dll!__vcrt_FlsGetValue(unsigned long) Line 401 C++
```

I've looked up multiple solutions such as reinstalling the x64 and x86 re-distributable for visual studio 2015 and enabling microsoft symbols but I still get this error. It seems to be caused by vcruntime140.dll.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program to see where the problem occurs? You don't initialize `mapCols` and `mapRows`, and then without checking that opening and reading the file succeeded, you do a lot based on these numbers. I'd maybe look at this. You also manage your memory manually, have you considered using `std::vector` instead?

Comment: @melak47 I've now initialized mapCols and mapRows. After debugging, it's crashing in the first for loop in Game.cpp at "mapData[i] = new int[mapCols];"

Comment: Did you inspect the values of `mapCols` and `mapRows`, did they make sense? You still don't check if reading from the file succeeded. All I can do is repeat [this advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884057/access-violation-exception-while-calling-malloc-new#comment53598609_32884057)

Comment: After testing it appears the file is not being read in properly. I imported mapdata.txt into the project and renamed the Resource Files folder to Assets but it's still not being read in properly.

Comment: Check the "working directory" setting, your program may not run where you expect it to, and thus not find your files.

Comment: thanks! That worked however now it seems that playerTexture.loadFromFile("Assets/actor.png"); is causing the same problem however actor.png is in that directory along with the mapdata.txt which is being read in correctly. I'm not sure what the problem is now.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem. I included as additional dependencies the dynamic libraries:

```
sfml-graphics-d.lib
sfml-window-d.lib
sfml-system-d.lib
```

and it works.

But keep in mind my configurations were set to Active (Debug).